# Who was the crowd around the villain at the end of “Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker”?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the end of *Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker*, the protagonist stands before the villain, they're surrounded by a crowd of thousands. Who are those in the crowd?

Comment: I imagined this was not a crowd of actual people, but an empty amphitheatre filled with the memories of all the Sith through time.

Comment: I love that idea, but somebody had to build all those ships.

Comment: The way that the imagery flashed and floated confirms this 'memories' or rather 'spirits' of past Sith, as does the dialog. @HDave the guys building and manning the ships were ah, building and manning the ships.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While not a lot is yet known about them, they are considered to be,

## [Sith Loyalists](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_loyalist) and/or the [Sith Eternal](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_Eternal)!!

> Sith loyalists were men who served and aided Darth Sidious and were
> **strong supporters of the Sith Eternal**. The assassin Ochi was one such
> person.

And according to *Rise of Skywalker* Visual Dictionary the Sith Eternal are

> **The Sith Eternal was an organization of cultists loyal to the Sith
> religion who continued the Sith belief and sought to resurrect its
> tradition. The Sith Eternal were followers of the Dark Lord of the
> Sith and Emperor, the Sith Lord Darth Sidious.** The Sith Eternal spent
> years building the largest armada known to the galaxy, the Sith fleet,
> as part of the Emperor's plan of revenge to use the Final Order to
> build a new Empire. However, the Sith Eternal were ultimately
> defeated at the Battle of Exegol, preventing the rebirth of the Sith
> and ensuring their extinction.

---

<sub>Just making a note that there is not yet a strong distinction between groups (Sith Loyalists, Knights of Ren, Acolytes of the Beyond, Alchemists, Sith Eternal) that are all loyal to the Sith, as it appears many were serving the same cause, but it appears that **The Sith Eternal** are the source cause and are the ones likely situated on Exegol according to the latest updates.</sub>

Comment: Although one could argue that won’t stop the remaining Imperials from trying to rebuild again. Just without Sith leadership/help the next time.........if there is a next time.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan I sure hope there isn‘t a next time.

Comment: @JakeGould I think it's very likely that Rey's story will continue and that being birthed out of the Skywalker Saga suggests that some things, including the elusive way Sidious was brought back and her relationship to it, will be baggage that feeds into wherever they go next, but there is a bigger picure here because it was not just Palatine they were trying to bring back, but the Sith and I think that it also unlikely that all of the materials/Sith loyalists that were used to bring Sidious back were solely on Exegol.

Comment: If they were biologically normal people who just were supporters of Sith ideology, what did they do for all these decades that we've never seen them anywhere? They just enjoy sitting in a damp and dark cave, murmuring menacingly? What do they do? What do they eat?

Comment: Also not over thinking it---most of these stories get fleshed out somewhere else, because there are always questions left unanswered or not perfectly clarified and IMO there is a lot of intentional ambiguity in TROS and the story of Rey and Ben helps transition into a new era that doesn't have to be so aggressively beholden to what came before, despite that I doubt it will be disregarded either, because of the choices with Rey (and Finn).

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not sure from which one of the listed sources this is taken from and/or if we know for certain that TKOR were Sith Loyalists outright, but it implied in these passages, despite turning into such by the end of TROS, but the updated entry states they were mildly force-sensitive: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Knights_of_Ren

Comment: These loyalists weren't in the amphitheater though, i agree they were most likely the ones who built the ships, but if they were all there, why did they fade in and out of existence? as the scene panned around.

Comment: The problem lies in not being able to well distinguish between groups and whose alive and whose apart of something else, which is why I include the Sith Eternal in the answer. They are probably the "cultist" in the amphitheater, but that doesn't mean they are not also loyalists, since a loyalist implies being loyal to the Sith. But I added a note and edited to better clarify.